# How to retrieve a specific field whith a special character in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list that contains those fields:

```
msg = ['you', 'must', 'pay', 'before', '$id2{8},', 'your', 'balance', 'is', '$id1{5}']
```

I want to retrieve all the fields that contain the character `$` and put them in a variable

I've tried this, but I don't know how I can specify the fields that contain `$`:

```
for iter in msg:
     if iter == "...":
        print iter
```

Comment: why not just iter[0] == '$'

Comment: [iter is a builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter). It's best not to overshadow it with a variable of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for item in msg:    
     if '$' in item:
        starting=item.index('{')
        ending=item.index('}')

        print item[3:starting],item[starting+1:ending]
```

you can search it by just `if '$' in item`

u can also try

```
lis=[(item[3],item[5]) for item in msg if item .startwith('$') ]
```

note: please do not use `iter` as variable it is a `built in` function in python

Comment: please i want to retrieve in this string $id2{8} the decimal which is just after $id and also the decimal which is between {} how can i do it please?

Comment: No i don't know how can i do it

Comment: but the id can be more than one decimal example $id20{8} so the item 5 can't be the desired field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function for this:

```
result = filter(lambda x: '$' in x, msg)
```